# What is the Gem to Gold exchange rate in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I believe it is market-based, but what is the approximate ratio (e.g. 5:1, 2:1, etc)?

Comment: I'm afraid this might be too localized since whatever answer provided will be out dated as soon as the ratio changes.

Comment: It can always be edited to ask a different question

Comment: @Domocus Generally, we try not to change the intent of the question, even if it's going to get closed.  We try to help the author by letting him know what's wrong with it, but it's up to the author to decide if he wants to change the question.  As such, I have rolled back this edit.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that it is market based, and there is no answer that will always hold true; however, you can always check to see exactly what the ratio is by pressing the "o" key to bring up the currency exchange window. You can also see past trends in the currency exchange rate.

Comment: It's market based, and not reliant on prices that people set like the auction house which I am personally very happy for. It fluctuates up and down based on how many gems are being put up and being bought.